# DNS Load Balance for Static Website

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, iis, load-balancing, round-robin

This is more of a educational question in comparison to a production environment. I have an AD environment with two IIS servers hosting the identical website content. For arguements sake lets say it is only accessed internally.

I want to load balance the DNS record: `myintranet.mydomain.com` between the two IIS servers using Windows DNS.

Is this possible in Windows alone with IIS? How would I go about setting this up?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DNS Round Robin (which is enabled by default on a Windows DNS server), but this isn't true load balancing. The DNS server will rotate multiple A records for the resource (once you've created the A records) to the clients querying those A records.

For "truer" load balancing you should look at something like NLB or Application Request Routing.

Comment: How would I configure the above though, if all clients access via myintranet.mydomain.com? Would I just create two A records for it poitning to WEBSRV01 and WEBSRV02 IPs?

Comment: For DNS Round Robin, yes. myintranet.mydomain.com - 1.1.1.1 and myintranet.mydomain.com - 1.1.1.2, for instance.